# Kotlin error that says Value CreateAccountResponse(success of type java.lang String

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am having trouble trying to solve this error this is the code

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class CreateAccountResponse(
    val success: Boolean,
    val message: String?,
    val data: AccountInfo?)
```

With that error  that says Value CreateAccountResponse -

> success of type java.lang String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I tried changing the `boolean` to `string` but i still had the same error.